# Hive table from JSON data using pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I wanted to create one flat hive table from json data which his coming from another hive table(placed in one column-event_data). Below is the json data structure. I have created hive table by using later view but now i wanted to use pyspark with some UDF's to create the hive table.

```
'{"callId":"0000000","journey":{"channel":{"out":"sssss@icloud.com","outbound":"EMAIL"}},"application":{"componentId":"23456","name":"dfgt-ghy-svc","applicationReferenceId":"SRFC98756RD"},"servicingDetail":{"offerAttributes":{"id":"ADLC0110000"},"offerCommunicationAttributes":{"id":"CFRGTV10098","status":"SUCCESS"}},"customerInfo":{"calledInAccount":"ERFCVDG9801"},"correlationId":"9845-sd76-sdfr87","fulfiller":{"id":"DEFC1009","category":"TST","entity":"colleague"},"platform":{"name":"v-generation","id":"37664859"}}'
```

I need only 4 columns need to extract which are `callId`, `correlationId`, `servicingDetail -offerAttributes-id`,`fulfiller-id`

Please help me to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

At first, create OutputTable in hive.

Then, select data using **get_json_object() function** from single column table and insert that data into final table. Refer for [get_json_object()](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-get_json_object).

```
INSERT INTO table OutputTable 
SELECT 
    get_json_object(event_data,'$.callId') as callId, 
    get_json_object(event_data,'$.correlationId') as correlationId,
    get_json_object(event_data,'$.servicingDetail.offerAttributes.id') as servicingDetail_offerAttributes_id,
    get_json_object(event_data,'$.fulfiller.id') as fulfiller_id,
FROM SingleColumnTable;
```

## **1st edit - Solution for pyspark**

Read single column table into dataframe (suppose df name is dfSingleColumnedData), then apply below logic to get each column wise data. finally select your required columns.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from collections import OrderedDict

def convert_to_row(d: dict) -> Row:
    return Row(**OrderedDict(sorted(d.items())))

dfSingleColumnedData.rdd.map(convert_to_row).toDF()
```

Comment: I want to get o/p from pyspark code. kindly convert in pyspark.